# What is the difference between COM dll server and COM exe server?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I would like to know how we can decide that we have to use COM dll server or COM  exe server.

Answer (score 6):

COM DLL server is called INPROC server, it's loaded into caller process as a dynamic library. In general communication with INPROC server is more effective, because it does not have to do RPC.

COM EXE server can be local or remote, but in both cases the communication is done via Remote Procedure Call, so it's more heavy.

If you don't have specific requirements I would always go for INPROC server (COM DLL), simply because it's more efficient and easier to debug, because it works in the same process.

Comment: Thanks for quick helpful reply